# how to make p2p connection in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, p2p, internet-connection, net.p2p

I am trying to make an android app in kotlin which have feature of P2P connection between two devices in spite of reason they are not in a same wifi. They should be able to create a server-client or whatever connection is possible but they should not include any other third party (expect they can use third party only in authentication: if that feature is added)
I want this feature for making a messaging app which doesn't use central server while two are chatting.

I had heard about web-rtc but i want to know is it possible to share other files rather than video and audio call. I want to share files using this feature and want to live stream video from one device to 3-4 clients(one-way only) is that possible.